# Can anyone help me on SAML setup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ibm-domino

I have installed domino 9 server and successfully configured IDP and other necessary setting in domino side.

now i installed the windows server 2008 (small business server) along with adfs 2.0.

As instructed <[here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndsebetaforum.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=C6F8337CA6DCC1FB85257AD300574EF3)> i completed my setup, but after completed all these step when i try to open domino application it is redirecting me to active directory login page , prompted for user name and password i entered everything, I'm getting the below error.

> MSAD.saml.local 
>   There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
>   If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference number to identify the problem.
>   Reference number: 39c4db33-9736-4a6e-8023-079a32903d4a

it seems active directory issue, no clue how to handle this.

Can anyone suggest me any good blog to configure ADFS 2.0 for domino saml integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check from Domino http log if this request reaches the Domino server. If it does then check the URL parameters, HTTP headers and cookies to see if the user information has been passed forward by Active Directory.

Setting Domino to log to *domlog.nsf* wil help.